# Azure blob storage shared access policies apply/remove

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a container in Azure blob storage with the Access Policy set to "Blob".  The container has existing blobs that I would like to protect with a Shared Access Policy.

I noticed if I create a container shared access policy...

```
var sharedPolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
{
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(120),
    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write
};
permissions.SharedAccessPolicies.Add(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), sharedPolicy);
_blobContainer.SetPermissions(permissions);
```

I am still able to read the existing blobs.  I expected the existing blobs to be "protected" by the newly created SAP.

1. How can I apply a SAP to an existing blob?
2. Can all SAP's be removed from a container to expose all the blobs publicly again (assuming you know the url)?  Or does removing the SAP make the blobs inaccessible somehow?
3. If I am using SAP's to protect the blobs, can I set the container's Access Policy to "private" and have it still work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tinkered with this for a while.  Here is what I observed...

**Access Policy = Blob**

Anyone that knows the URI to the blob can read the blob (regardless of SAP's).

**Access Policy = Private**

To read you must...

1. Connect with the storage access key
2. OR have a valid Shared Access Signature
3. OR have a valid Stored Access Policy (on the container)

Comment: Yes, if you want to protect your blob via SAS, you must set the container access policy to private.